# CSS for tag with certain attribute?

Tags: css

I'd like to set up a form with CSS. I'm using `#email input {}` to change the look of the inputs. However, I'd like the submit button to have a slightly different style. How can I do something like this:

```
#email input {
    width: 614px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #000000;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
#email input:type:submit {
    width: 620px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #000000;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors).  The square brackets match based on attributes of the element.

In your case, it would be like this:

```
#email input[type="submit"] { /* your styles here */ }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
#email input[type="submit"] {}
```

Should do the trick...